# How do I get automapper to map enums that are part of a list of child objects

Tags: automapper

I've got the majority of my automapper maps working but I'm facing a problem trying to translate an enum from the value to the string when part of list of child objects.  I have the enum to string converter working when at the top level but it seems when I am converting from RecipeStep to RecipeStepResource it isn't using the map defined for Ingredient to IngredientResource and therefore the conversion from enum to string isn't being called.

I've looked around but can't seem to find a similar example to work from and am having trouble deciphering the automapper help on this which says it should automatically pick up the map defined, which it doesn't seem to be, unsure if this is because the Ingredient items are part of a list.  Major code snippets below, any help appreciated.

Model:

```
public class RecipeStep
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IList<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public Timer Timer { get; set; }


    public int RecipeID { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [ForeignKey("RecipeID")]
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ETypeOfIngredient Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Amount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public EUnitOfMeasure Unit { get; set; }

    public int RecipeStepID { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [ForeignKey("RecipeStepID")]
    public RecipeStep RecipeStep { get; set; }
}
```

Resources:

```
public class RecipeStepResource
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<IngredientResource> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public TimerResource Timer { get; set; }
}

public class IngredientResource
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public int RecipeStepID { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping code:

```
        CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientResource>()
            .ForMember(src => src.Type,
                       opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Type.ToDescriptionString()))
            .ForMember(src => src.Unit,
                       opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Unit.ToDescriptionString()));

        CreateMap<Timer, TimerResource>();

        CreateMap<RecipeStep, RecipeStepResource>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Ingredients,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Ingredients))
            .ForMember(src => src.Timer,
                       opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Timer));
```

Enum to string conversion code:

```
    public static string ToDescriptionString<TEnum>(this TEnum @enum)
    {
        FieldInfo info = @enum.GetType().GetField(@enum.ToString());
        var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        return attributes?[0].Description ?? @enum.ToString();
    }
```

**What I have tried:**

- Creating an `Ingredient -> IngredientResource` map
- Creating a `List<Ingredient> -> List<IngredientResource>` map
- Adding an AfterMap call to the `List<Ingredient> -> List<IngredientResource>` map to convert the enum value

None of these have worked.  Really struggling to understand why AutoMapper is not picking up the Ingredient to IngredientResource map for a List property on the RecipeStep object, I thought it would have done this automatically.

Comment: Try [EnumMemberAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute?view=netcore-3.1) instead. That's built in and you don't need a resolver anymore. Other than that, check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Thanks for that @LucianBargaoanu, from the executionplan it looks like my problem is because I only have a map for Ingredient -> IngredientResource and not List<Ingredient> -> List<IngredientResource>.  I've been trying to get that map working but I can't seem to configure it to handle enum handling for the properties in each Ingredient object.  Any additional thoughts?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: Thanks for that @LucianBargaoanu, I believe I have tried what the help documents suggest but I'm still not getting the desired response, really don't understand why this is proving so tricky.

Comment: Start with a very simple example like in the docs and work your way up. Clearly you're missing smth basic.

Answer (score 1):

The issue came down to the parent object, I had it incorrectly mapped with both the model and resource files referring to RecipeStep, instead of RecipeStep -> RecipeStepResource.  Really want to thank @Lucian for helping me and making me go back to basics to work through the understanding from a simpler standpoint and building up to a representative model.